# Export Google Apps Domain to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is is possible to export the entire Google Apps domain (docs/sites/calendars/emails/etc), basically every thing that is hosted by Google Apps, to an internal SharePoint site/ area?

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps has a full API that could be leveraged to do this.  Alternatively, it appears that [Metalogix has a product](http://blogs.technet.com/b/whymicrosoft/archive/2011/03/07/migrate-google-apps-content-to-sharepoint.aspx) out there designed to do just what you are asking about.  I have never used it and cannot personally recommend it.